# Changing entire list colour when hovering over one link with css

Tags: css, styles, hover, hyperlink

*** ok, thought i had it but now i don't.
I'm trying to do the colour links with organic tabs, the colours are no longer working on the links, my tabs have stopped working and my page layout gets messed up when I add in the example one div tag.
any thoughts? 
http://jsfiddle.net/kb0440/74vuX/
. The portfolio content is suppose to go beside the sidebar on the same plain. thanks!

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this, I cant seem to figure it out.
I'm trying to get this effect with my list:
http://digitalmash.com/
I want all other links to go grey when I hover over one and I want them to all be colourful like that. I'm trying to use it with organic tabs js and Im pretty new at this so trying to figure it out has just turned my brain to mush! any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the original code here or in a JSFiddle?  That way, when you fix the problem, this question will still be useful to other visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :-)

HTML:

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li class="first">Item 1</li>
    <li class="second">Item 2</li>
    <li class="third">Item 3</li>
    <li class="fourth">Item 4</li>
</ul>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
div ul:hover li {
    color:#CCC;
}
ul li.first, div ul li.first:hover {
    color:#F00;
}
ul li.second, div ul li.second:hover {
    color:#0F0;
}
ul li.third, div ul li.third:hover {
    color:#00F;
}
ul li.fourth, div ul li.fourth:hover {
    color:#0FA;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/RAWgv/)**

Comment: This doesn't do as specified : colors aren't apparent if you don't hover the ul.

Comment: Thanks @dystroy, i missed that part. Edited!

Answer (score 1):

With colors:

```
.test:hover > div {    
    color: #777;
}

.blue, .test:hover > .blue:hover {
    color: blue;
}

.red, .test:hover > .red:hover {
    color: red;
}

.orange, .test:hover > .orange:hover {
    color: orange;
}
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/NqAWA/**

Comment: thanks! :) http://jsfiddle.net/kb0440/BApKG/ I tried adding organic tabs and I think I messed something up with the styling. any thoughts? thanks again!

Comment: nevermind, i got it! I needed to bump the colour classes in with the a href. thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this.

**Here's one using CSS3 :**

```
<span>
<a id=a href=# title=AAA>AAAAA</a>
<a id=b href=# title=CCC>BBBBB</a>
<a id=c href=# title=CDDEZ>epupzotfrez eze</a>
</span>

span:hover a {color:grey;}
a {text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold;}
span:not(:hover) #a, #a:hover { color:red;}
span:not(:hover) #b, #b:hover { color:blue;}
span:not(:hover) #c, #c:hover { color:green;}
```

[DEMONSTRATION](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/B3cyS/2/)

​
**Here's another one using javascript (here with jquery but you may convert it to vanilla) :**

```
<span>
<a href=# title=AAA color=red>AAAAA</a>
<a href=# title=CCC color=blue>BBBBB</a>
<a href=# title=CDDEZ color=green>epupzotfrez eze</a>
</span>
​
a {text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold;}

function color() {
    $('a').each(function(){
        $(this).css('color', $(this).attr('color'));
    });
}
$('a').mouseenter(function(){
    $('a').css('color','grey');
    $(this).css('color', $(this).attr('color'));
});
$('span').mouseleave(color);
color();
```

An advantage of the second solution is that you don't have to make an entry in your css for every link.

[DEMONSTRATION](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/H5XEs/)

Comment: And it also leads to easy specificity issues. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:not

Comment: @LaurentBrieu I added another solution using javascript